# JSON object is undefined

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I am a student working on a movie browser project for my university's library website. I have some Javascript experience, but other than research for this project I have no experience with XML or JSON.

I must query WorldCat Search API for all DVDs in our holdings using a hidden API key, and convert the MARCXML results to JSON. The library server does not support server-side scripting, so I chose to use Yahoo Pipes which allows me to "hide" the API key in a private string and it returns the results as JSON.

My issue is that sometimes (but certainly not always) I receive an error message:

`TypeError: root is undefined`

I'm assuming the inconsistency with this error is due to load times (maybe the Javascript is trying to execute before the JSON object has completely loaded? How can I improve the efficiency of my code to avoid this error? Thank you for any advice.

Below you will find a shortened example of my code that sometimes recreates this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var my_JSON_object = {};
var movieArray = new Array();
var subject = 'Science+Fiction';
var recordSet = 1;

loadJSON(0);

function loadJSON(set) 
{
    if (set == 0)
        var yahooPipe = 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=b54472aff1548e93022d07fddfd6aa38&_render=json&maximumRecords=20&startRecord=1&subject='+subject+'&_callback=getData';
    else
        var yahooPipe = 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=b54472aff1548e93022d07fddfd6aa38&_render=json&maximumRecords=20&startRecord='+((set*20)+1)+'&subject='+subject+'&_callback=getNextData';
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];         
    var newJS = document.createElement('script');

    newJS.type = 'text/javascript';
    newJS.src = yahooPipe;
    head.appendChild(newJS);
}

function getData(json)
{
    my_JSON_object = json;
    if (my_JSON_object.value.items[0].numberOfRecords>0)
        prepData(0);
    else
        alert("No results...");
}

function getNextData(json)
{
    my_JSON_object = json;
    prepData(recordSet);
}

function loadData()
{   
    loadJSON(recordSet);
    recordSet++;
}

function prepData(set)
{
    var root = my_JSON_object.value.items[0];   

    if (set == 0 && root.numberOfRecords == 1)
    {
        root.records.record[0] = root.records.record;
    }

    for (var i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        if (root.records.record[i]==undefined)  
        {
            document.getElementById('A1').innerHTML=root.numberOfRecords;
            document.getElementById('A2').innerHTML=movieArray[set*20+i-1];
            break;
        }

        for (var j=0; j<root.records.record[i].recordData.record.datafield.length; j++)
        {
            if (root.records.record[i].recordData.record.datafield[j].tag == 245)
            {               
                for (var k=0; k<root.records.record[i].recordData.record.datafield[j].subfield.length; k++)
                {
                    if (root.records.record[i].recordData.record.datafield[j].subfield[k].code == "a")
                    {
                        movieArray[i+(set*20)] = root.records.record[i].recordData.record.datafield[j].subfield[k].content; 
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (set*20<root.numberOfRecords)
        loadData();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Results:</b><span id="A1"></span></p>
<p><b>Title(last record):</b><span id="A2"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When/Where is `getData` called?

Comment: its the `callback`-function within `loadJSON(set)`. I've put you code into this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4suV/1/) and removed all errors, jsLint raised. I also put the function-call `loadJSON(0);` at the very end of the code, so that all function (including the callback) are defined, when they are called which is probably not the problem here, but anyway.

Comment: Thanks nozzleman, your revisions greatly improved the performance and reliability of the process from what few tests I have done so far. I still get the same error, but only when I stress test it (changing subject to 'Drama' yields over 3000 results which still hangs up), but I believe I can avoid that using other limiters in the query.